# In a multi-level index pandas dataframe loop starting at n then loop again starting at n+1, n+2, nth over whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, multi-index

I have the following dataframe:

```
###Test data

data = {'SELECTION_ID': [10050745,15204174,20307467,19748256,11510486,15613790,18446246,11744872,
                        10050744,15404174,20307567,19748276,11520486,15613490,18416246,11754872],

        'BSP': [3.335767,3.900000,5.374437,11.293687,11.500000,17.364754,28.939854,61.384857,
               2.365767,4.900000,6.374437,12.293687,15.500000,16.364754,29.939854,62.384857],

        'WIN_LOSE': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

        'EVENT_ID': [116144500,116144500,116144500,116144500,116144500,116144500,116144500, 116144500,
                    116144501,116144501,116144501,116144501,116144501,116144501,116144501, 116144501]

       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['SELECTION_ID','BSP','WIN_LOSE','EVENT_ID'])

df = df.sort_values(["EVENT_ID","BSP"])
df.set_index(['EVENT_ID', 'SELECTION_ID'], inplace=True)
```

I want to loop over the index `'EVENT_ID'`. This starts at index `0` I then want to loop over starting at index `1` and so forth. I only have two `EVENT_ID` but the real data has an extensive amount of `EVENT_ID`.

My attempt:

```
number_of_index = len(df.groupby('EVENT_ID'))

number_of_events = np.arange(0, number_of_index, 1)

for event in number_of_events:

        print("Loop 1:", event)

        for EVENT_ID in df.groupby(level=0).iloc[event:].iterrows():

            print("Loop 2:", event)
```

I was expecting this to return:

```
Loop 1: 0
Loop 2: 0
Loop 2: 0

Loop 1: 1
Loop 1: 1
```

Though I got the error:

```
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'iloc' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

Comment: Why do you need to loop, specifically by the level? `df.groupby(level=0)` does not have `iloc` property.

Comment: As for the real data, I am applying a function to each `EVENT_ID` index. This is not shown in the example above for ease of readability.

Comment: As the error message says, after `groupby` you need to `apply` something before you can `iloc`, as `groupby` is just a group of data frames.

Comment: A rule of thumb is to write your function so that it can be vectorized across the input. Anyhow, you can loop with `for idx, row in df.iterrows():` then in this case, `idx` will be a pair `event, event_id`.

Comment: `for idx, row in df.iterrows():` this iterates over all the `SELECTION_ID ` over the number of `EVENT_ID `. I want to iterate over the `EVENT_ID ` which starts at index 0 then iterates again at index 1 so forth for `EVENT_ID `.